# Login Attempt on Twitter throwing ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN

Tags: authentication, twitter, certificate

All of a sudden I am unable to log in to Twitter from my machine. While there is no way to reach and expect Twitter support. I am expecting some help from the community here.

I can log in to my account from some other locations e.g. a service placed on AWS cloud in US region.

I am trying to log in from Pakistan but it is failing. I get errors as per the attached screenshots.

How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same from South Africa. Seems either we have been hacked somehow or Twitter itself. Also, my Twitter icon has changed into a fox!

[Twitter with the Fox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zm1E.jpg)

[Zoomed on Twitter with the Fox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7kSr.png)

I found this article on Comodo's site:

How to Fix NET ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN as the Site Owner
This is a key pinning error. HTTP public key pinning (HPKP) was a great idea, in theory, but it’s prohibitively difficult for all but the most sophisticated and technically mature organizations. Regular website owners should NOT attempt it.

Chances are, someone suggested you attempt key pinning, which didn’t go as planned. The error itself is communicating that one of the keys you have pinned isn’t bound to the certificate you pinned it to. These keys are not interchangeable; failing to pin the right keys to the correct certificates can break your entire site… As it just did.

And it’s not just your own keys you need to pin; you also need to pin the keys for the rest of your certificate chain — save the root, whose key is included in the root stores. Keep in mind that when a visitor arrives at your website, the server hosting your site presents the user’s browser with the certificate. The browser uses those public keys to verify the signature on each certificate and trace it back to the certificate that left it.

Even if you pinned your own certificate’s key correctly, mis-pinning any other intermediate public keys can still cause this problem

The fix is simple:

STOP PINNING YOUR KEYS!

It’s like the old joke about the guy who says to his doctor, “it hurts when I do this.” To which his doctor responds, “well don’t do that, then.” This situation is the same scenario. Experts advise against key pinning. We advise against key pinning. This is one time it doesn’t pay to be subversive.

Simply re-install your certificate and any intermediates in the standard way. This may require you to remove the previous configuration, but that shouldn’t take longer than a minute or two. Just follow the STANDARD instructions and your site should work just fine.

Just stop pinning those keys.

Let me know if you win?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am a not a technical user and I am not sure I did something related to ssl pining. 
1. How can i stop pinning those keys ? 
2. How can i remove previous configuraitons from browser ?